# how to do wind turbine layout optimization with multiple hub-height wind turbines using Openmdao

Tags: algorithm, optimization, openmdao

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

I am trying to optimize wind turbine layout having different hub-height turbines using OpenMDAO (0.10.3.2). I have coded different components to calculate AEP, fatigue and ultimate loads and cost. I am new to this optimization problem where I need to optimize with different hub-height turbines. I did not find any code related this optimization problem on internet. Hub-heights are 85, 90, 100, 120 and 140 (m) and a wind farm has total 25 wind turbines where we have to find optimal hub-height among above mentioned hub-heights for each turbine to maximize wind farm AEP and minimize cost. hub-height is an input to OpenMDAO components and assembly (connect all components).

Please help me find optimization algorithm to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old version of OpenMDAO. I suggest you change over to using [OpenMDAO 2.0](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.1.0/index.html). Your question is also way to broad, and without more details there isn't a very good way to answer it in any detail.

The flow lab at BYU is doing a lot of work, relevant to this. The most recent reference I can provide is work by Stanley, Ning, and Dykes on wind farm optimization with different hub heights, titled "Optimization of Turbine Design in Wind Farms with Multiple Hub Heights, Using Exact Analytic Gradients and Structural Constraints". There is also some earlier work published as a [conference publication.](http://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2875&context=facpub)

Comment: To solve this kind of problem, do I have to code my own optimization algorithm or can be solved by existing algorithms?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Flow Lab and their work related to this.